# Window Creation Fails and Returns -1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, glfw

Hi I've been learning OpenGL and C++ over the past few weeks and thought of making a Engine (CDark is the name to be specific), and have encountered a problem while trying to create a window.

**the problem is that:**

When I try to run my application, it returns -1; and closes the window.

The error checker I use to make sure window creation is successful looks something like this:

```
    if (!win)
    {
        glfwTerminate(); /* For now I'm going to use GLFW to the heavy lifting I'll abstract          
                more it later on */
        std::cout << "No Window!" << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }
```

I don't what is the cause for this problem though, I've checked the GLFW documentation and I've done everything correctly (I think). The only I'm not very experienced at is OOP but that's not to say I've never used OOP before.

I've tried referencing from other engines but haven't got any solution nor while googling.

I also checked my code for any small mistakes but didn't see anything.

**PS:** If I've missed anything or haven't gave enough information then please comment below and also
here's the link to the Github: https://github.com/mehroof200/CDark-Engine/tree/main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `Window.cpp` in this function:

```
GLFWwindow* graphics::Window::Window_c::window_create(int width, int height, const char* name, GLFWmonitor *monitor, GLFWwindow *share)
{
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, name, monitor, share);


    return 0;
}
```

your return 0 instead of the glfw's return, and then in your main function:

```
win = c.window_create(640, 480, "SLAP", NULL, NULL);

    if (!win)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        std::cout << "No Window!" << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }
```

you assign the result of `Window_c::window_create` function to `win`, which would always be 0. your `if(!win)` will always fail. correct the `return 0` and try it again.